# Increase height of textview in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this textview

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/time1"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:text="text" >
```

how can increase the height of textview from 1dp to 50dp by animation(translate) using java code

thank you all

Comment: Check this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13757723/2536878 and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063466/how-to-expand-a-layout-height-with-animation

Comment: lol I searched too much didn't find this but thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

```
ValueAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myTextView, "scaleY", 2.0f);
animation.setDuration(1000);
animation.start();
```

Comment: when I set a textview then .ofInt - .setDuration - .start get error...!